# I am trying to use react-app-rewired for changing file-loader config

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, three.js

I'm using react-app-rewired to change the webpack config. My intention is to be able to load GLTF files into react for threejs.

I found an example using the npm package. https://www.npmjs.com/package/gltf-webpack-loader. I have tried the following code but I getting an error with my webpack. The following code is my config-overrides.js

```
module.exports = function override(config, env) {
  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.(gltf)$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: "gltf-webpack-loader"
      }
    ]
  });

  config = { ...config,   {
    test: /\.(bin)$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: "file-loader",
        options: {}
      }
    ]
  }
};

  return config;
};
```

I want to be able to load GLTF files into a react application.